# Laravel 4 with Confide Auth::check() messes up JSON response

Tags: php, jquery, json, laravel-4

I have a pretty simple method that creates a new record in a table. But i only want this action allowed by logged in users (Laravel / Confide). All works fine without checking if a user is logged in. The script nicely returns a JSON string to my jQuery Ajax call.

But as soon as i add the 'if(Auth::check()' check i get a huge extra string in the result (the complete User class!?!?! with the JSON encoded array attached to it), messing up my JSON encoded array. Is this normal behaviour or am i missing something here?

This is the working method:

```
public function create()
{
    //if(Auth::check()) {

    //$userId = Auth::getUser()->id; // Get logged in user id

    $folder = new Folder();
    $folder->parent_id = Input::get('fid');
    $folder->title = 'Nieuwe map';
    $folder->alias = 'nieuwe-map-'.time();
    //$folder->created_by = $userId;
    $folder->save();

    return Response::json(array('success'));

    //} else {
        //return Response::json(array('error'));
    //}

}
```

This is the result:

```
["success"]
```

When i add the Auth check i get this result:

```
<!--
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {



    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password');

    /**
     * Get the unique identifier for the user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    /**
     * Get the password for the user.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Get the token value for the "remember me" session.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRememberToken()
    {
        return $this->remember_token;
    }

    /**
     * Set the token value for the "remember me" session.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return void
     */
    public function setRememberToken($value)
    {
        $this->remember_token = $value;
    }

    /**
     * Get the column name for the "remember me" token.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRememberTokenName()
    {
        return 'remember_token';
    }

    /**
     * Get the e-mail address where password reminders are sent.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getReminderEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

} -->["success"]
```

Comment: Would you mind posting the contents of your `json` view file? If you just want to send a json response can't you just `return Response::json('json' => ['success'] )`?

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/01b39d781945fff6bdba

Comment: <?php header('Content-type: application/json'); ?>
{{ json_encode($json) }}

Comment: You shouldn't do such things as setting the content type in your views. I don't know the whole process of what laravel does internally when responding with a view, but chances are high that some background processing comes in your way. You'd be better off using `Response::json()`. See if the code I provided in my first comment works for you.

Comment: I tried the Response::json() before. It didn't work so i was searching for other ways, and along the way using stupid 'solutions' ;). Using Response::json has the same problem, it works great but when calling Auth::check() the whole thing becomes useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First i was convinced the error was in Confide. But the lack of comments / answers and the fact i couldn't find anything about it on the internet i went diving into the code. The result was 5 minutes of 'work' and i fixed it. I made a great mistake!

I wanted to keep the old User model in case i needed it some other time. So when installing Confide i changed the User model into:

```
<?php

use Zizaco\Confide\ConfideUser;

class User extends ConfideUser {

}

?>
<!--
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {



    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password');

    /**
     * Get the unique identifier for the user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    /**
     * Get the password for the user.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Get the token value for the "remember me" session.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRememberToken()
    {
        return $this->remember_token;
    }

    /**
     * Set the token value for the "remember me" session.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return void
     */
    public function setRememberToken($value)
    {
        $this->remember_token = $value;
    }

    /**
     * Get the column name for the "remember me" token.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRememberTokenName()
    {
        return 'remember_token';
    }

    /**
     * Get the e-mail address where password reminders are sent.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getReminderEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

} -->
```

So... there it is. When calling Auth:check() the uncommented code was printed :S Huge mistake ;)